# Null strings getting added to primary key field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null, primary-key

I have a primary key column `year` in my form.

Whenever the user creates a new form he should populate this field from the drop down.

But if the user makes a mistake and does not select anything from the drop down a null string gets appended `""`. And when post operation is selected the record gets created in the database table.

My question:
When user posts to the database after making his selection: the primary key column ends up accepting the null string `""`

Shouldn't this throw an error as the primary key field should never have a null/empty string ?

I checked the table creation script and the column is set to `Not Null` and no default value is assigned.

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Try validating your form before it hits the database, or you could put a trigger or check constraint to disallow the empty string.

Comment: You need to be **careful** with your terminology: `NULL` and a **empty string** are **NOT** the same. An empty string `""` should **not** be called *null* string - that's just asking for confusion and trouble .....

Comment: @marc_s Unless you're working with Oracle, then they are the same.

Comment: What is the datatype of `year` anyway? I would expect that to be some type of integer rather than a string.

Comment: @NullUserException: the OP clearly mentioned he's using **SQL Server** - that's the target product I'm referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NULL` and empty string are not synonymous in SQL Server as they are for Oracle. A PK can have an empty string.

Of course a PK must be unique so there can be only one such empty string unless it is a composite PK and the other columns have different values.

You should validate this before the insert attempt but could add a check constraint as a last line of defence.

Comment: Yes. This was an oversight and changing it in the code is not an option at the moment. Table change would have been easier. I looked at the option of adding a trigger but a trigger 'Before Insert' is not there for SQL Server

Comment: Ok. So I created a trigger which could be fired at every insert! Looks like its working. Thank you for all inputs!